# Only one row added "ORA-02290: check constraint (SYS_C0012762) violated ORA-01403: no data found"

Tags: oracle, function, package

I created a package which loads data from a staging table to a live table in Oracle DB. The package comprises of four functions which perform live load, update, insert and error check on the records. For some reason, I am only able to load one record from the staging table and then the following error occurs:

> ORA-02290: check constraint (VIQDATA.SYS_C0012762) violated ORA-01403: no data found

```
create or replace PACKAGE     VAL_PROC
AS
pi_sif_id        NUMBER := 0;

 CURSOR v_d_c (pi_sif_id NUMBER)
 IS
  SELECT * 
  FROM S_V_C_R
   WHERE SIF_ID =PI_SIF_ID
   AND   SVC_PROCESS_FLAG='N';

 TYPE v_d_c_t IS TABLE OF v_d_c%ROWTYPE;

 FUNCTION vr_live_load (pi_sif_id              NUMBER,
                           po_err_msg         OUT VARCHAR2,
                           po_success_count   OUT NUMBER,
                           po_failed_count    OUT NUMBER)
    RETURN NUMBER;

    FUNCTION check_error_record (p_v_d_r   IN     vr_dtl_cur%ROWTYPE,
                            lv_prc_code         OUT VARCHAR2,
                            lv_err_flag         OUT VARCHAR2)
    RETURN NUMBER;

    FUNCTION insert_v (p_v_d_r IN v_d_c%ROWTYPE, po_err_msg OUT VARCHAR2, po_prc_code OUT VARCHAR2)
    RETURN NUMBER;

    FUNCTION update_v (p_v_d_r IN v_d_c%ROWTYPE, po_err_msg OUT VARCHAR2, po_prc_code OUT VARCHAR2)
    RETURN NUMBER; 

END VAL_PROC;

create or replace PACKAGE BODY     VAL_PROC
AS
LV_X1_ID     SERIALS.X1_ID%TYPE;
LV_VC_ID     VR_COM.X1_ID%TYPE; --change name of this variable later

 FUNCTION vr_live_load(pi_sif_id              NUMBER, --live load function
                           po_err_msg         OUT VARCHAR2,
                           po_success_count   OUT NUMBER,
                           po_failed_count    OUT NUMBER) 
  RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  v_d_r             v_d_c_tbl;
  dup_prc                 NUMBER := 0;
  E_DUP_PRC               EXCEPTION;
  RETVAL                  NUMBER;
  pi_d_co             VARCHAR2(10);
  ERR_FLAG                VARCHAR2 (1);
  ret_prc_code            VARCHAR2 (15);
  lv_err_code             VARCHAR2 (1000);
  lv_found                NUMBER;
  lv_PRS_ID               NUMBER;
  lv_sif_filename         VARCHAR2 (200);
  lv_proc_success_count   NUMBER := 0;
  lv_proc_failed_count1   NUMBER := 0;
  BEGIN
  BEGIN
     SELECT COUNT (1)
       INTO DUP_PRC
       FROM s_fi
      WHERE SIF_ID = PI_SIF_ID AND s_p_f = 'P';

     IF dup_prc > 0
     THEN
        RAISE e_dup_prc;
     END IF;

     SELECT sif_filename
       INTO lv_sif_filename
       FROM s_fi
      WHERE sif_id = pi_sif_id;

     INSERT INTO p_s (PCG_CODE,
                                SIF_ID,
                                PRS_START_DATETIME,
                                sif_filename)
          VALUES ('V_ODL',
                  pi_sif_id,
                  SYSDATE,
                  lv_sif_filename)
       RETURNING PRS_ID
            INTO lv_PRS_ID;

     COMMIT;

     OPEN v_d_c(pi_sif_id);
     LOOP
        FETCH v_d_c
        BULK COLLECT INTO v_d_r
        LIMIT 1000;

        FOR i IN 1 .. v_d_r.COUNT
        LOOP
           retval :=
              check_error_record (p_v_d_r   => v_d_r(i),
                                  lv_prc_code      => ret_prc_code,
                                  lv_err_flag      => err_flag);

           IF retval = 0
           THEN
              IF ERR_FLAG = 'N'
              THEN
                 BEGIN
                    SELECT 1
                      INTO lv_found
                      FROM VR_COM
                     WHERE X1_ID = LV_X1_ID; --v_d_r(i).SVC_d_co = D.X1_ID;                         

                    retval :=
                       update_vr (p_v_d_r   => v_d_r (i),
                                      po_err_msg       => lv_err_code,
                                      po_prc_code      => ret_prc_code);

                    UPDATE STG_COM_RECORDS
                       SET PRC_CODE = ret_prc_code,
                           S_E_M = lv_err_code,
                           S_P_F = 'P'
                     WHERE S_ID = v_d_r (i).S_ID;

                    IF retval = 0
                    THEN
                       lv_proc_success_count := lv_proc_success_count + 1;
                    ELSE
                       lv_proc_failed_count1 := lv_proc_failed_count1 + 1;
                    END IF;
                 EXCEPTION
                    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
                    THEN
                       retval :=
                          insert_v (
                             p_v_d_r   => v_d_r (i),
                             po_err_msg       => lv_err_code,
                             po_prc_code      => ret_prc_code);


                       UPDATE STG_COM_RECORDS
                          SET PRC_CODE = ret_prc_code,
                              S_E_M = lv_err_code,
                              S_P_F = 'P'
                        WHERE S_ID = v_d_r(i).S_ID;

                       IF retval = 0
                       THEN
                          lv_proc_success_count :=
                             lv_proc_success_count + 1;
                       ELSE
                          lv_proc_failed_count1 :=
                             lv_proc_failed_count1 + 1;
                       END IF;
                 END;
              ELSE /*update table with prc_code when err_flag <> 'N' */
                 UPDATE STG_COM_RECORDS
                    SET PRC_CODE = ret_prc_code,
                        S_E_M = lv_err_code,
                        S_P_F = 'E'
                  WHERE S_ID = v_d_r (i).S_ID;

                 lv_proc_failed_count1 := lv_proc_failed_count1 + 1;
              END IF;
              ELSE              --if check_error_record return non-zero                      value
                  UPDATE STG_COM_RECORDS
                    SET PRC_CODE = ret_prc_code,
                        S_E_M = lv_err_code,
                        S_P_F = 'E'
                  WHERE S_ID = v_d_r (i).S_ID;

              lv_proc_failed_count1 := lv_proc_failed_count1 + 1;
           END IF;
           COMMIT;
        END LOOP;

        EXIT WHEN v_d_c%NOTFOUND;
     END LOOP;
     CLOSE v_d_c;
     COMMIT;               
         EXCEPTION
     WHEN e_dup_prc
     THEN                                         --file already processed
        UPDATE s_fi
           SET s_p_f = 'E'
         WHERE sif_id = pi_sif_id;

        COMMIT;
        po_err_msg := 'This File has previously been processed.';
  END;

  UPDATE s_fi
     SET s_p_f = 'P'
   WHERE sif_id = pi_sif_id;

  UPDATE p_s
     SET PLS_END_DATETIME = SYSDATE, PRS_ERRORED = 'Successful'
   WHERE PRS_ID = lv_PRS_ID;

  --Populate file load summary
 BEGIN
     p_p_f_l_s (P_SIF_ID => pi_sif_id);
  EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS
     THEN
        NULL;
  END; 

  COMMIT;

  po_success_count := lv_proc_success_count;
  po_failed_count := lv_proc_failed_count1;
  RETURN 0;
   EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS
  THEN
     lv_err_code := SQLERRM;

     UPDATE s_fi
        SET s_p_f = 'E'
      WHERE sif_id = pi_sif_id;

     UPDATE p_s
        SET PLS_END_DATETIME = SYSDATE, PRS_ERRORED = lv_err_code
      WHERE PRS_ID = lv_PRS_ID;

     COMMIT;
     po_err_msg := SQLERRM;

     CLOSE v_d_c;

     RETURN SQLCODE;

 END vr_live_load;

       FUNCTION insert_v (p_v_d_r IN v_d_c%ROWTYPE, po_err_msg OUT VARCHAR2,po_prc_code OUT VARCHAR2) --inserts records to live table 
   RETURN NUMBER
     IS
     RETNUM   number := 0;

      begin

    INSERT INTO VR_COM (VC_ID,
                               co_pe,
                             COUNTRY_CODE,
                             X1_ID,
                             TIME_PERIOD
                             )
          VALUES (VC_ID_SQ.NEXTVAL,
               p_v_d_r.s_perc,
               p_v_d_r.s_coun,
               (select X1_ID from SERIALS where d_co=p_v_d_r.SVC_d_co),
               p_v_d_r.s_time
               );

       po_prc_code := 'S11';
        RETURN retnum;
     EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS
     THEN
     PO_ERR_MSG := SQLERRM;
     PO_PRC_CODE := 'O11';
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SQLERRM :'||SQLERRM);         
     RETURN SQLCODE;

   END insert_v;

   FUNCTION update_vr (p_v_d_r IN v_d_c%ROWTYPE, po_err_msg OUT VARCHAR2,                     po_prc_code OUT VARCHAR2) --update the live table if data matches by ID 
     RETURN NUMBER
    IS
     LV_d_co     SERIALS.d_co%TYPE;
  BEGIN
  SELECT VRC.X1_ID, D.d_co
    INTO LV_VC_ID, LV_d_co
    FROM VR_COM VRC, SERIALS D
   WHERE VRC.X1_ID = D.X1_ID;

  update VR_COM
     set co_pe         = p_v_d_r.s_perc,      
         COUNTRY_CODE             = p_v_d_r.s_coun,
         TIME_PERIOD              = p_v_d_r.s_time                

   WHERE X1_ID = LV_VC_ID;
   return 0;
   EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS
  THEN
     po_err_msg := SQLERRM;
     PO_PRC_CODE := 'O11';
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SQLERRM :'||SQLERRM);
     RETURN SQLCODE;
   END update_vr;


    FUNCTION check_error_record (p_v_d_r   IN     v_d_c%ROWTYPE,
                            lv_prc_code         OUT VARCHAR2,
                            lv_err_flag         OUT VARCHAR2) --check error
    RETURN NUMBER
   IS
  --LV_d_co     SERIALS.d_co%TYPE;
  retnum      NUMBER := 0;
  lv_found    VARCHAR2 (10);
  LV_FLAG     varchar2 (2);
  LV_PROC_FLAG     VARCHAR2 (2);
  BEGIN
  lv_prc_code := NULL;
  lv_err_flag := NULL;

  BEGIN
  IF LV_X1_ID IS NOT NULL  THEN
  SELECT d_co, d_a_s_c
  INTO LV_X1_ID, LV_FLAG
  FROM SERIALS
  WHERE p_v_d_r.SVC_d_co =d_co;
  END IF; 

        lv_err_flag := 'N';
         EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
        THEN
           lv_prc_code := 'P5';
           lv_err_flag := 'Y';
           lv_proc_flag := 'E';
     END;

  IF p_v_d_r.SVC_d_co IS NULL
  THEN
     lv_prc_code := 'V2';
     lv_err_flag := 'Y'; 
  ELSIF p_v_d_r.s_perc IS NULL
  THEN
     lv_prc_code := 'V6';
     lv_err_flag := 'Y';
  ELSIF p_v_d_r.s_time IS NULL
  THEN
    lv_prc_code := 'V4';
    lv_err_flag := 'Y';
  ELSIF p_v_d_r.s_coun IS NULL
   THEN
    lv_prc_code := 'V1';
    lv_err_flag := 'Y';
  ELSE
    lv_prc_code := 'S11';
    lv_err_flag := 'N';
  end if;
  RETURN retnum;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
  THEN
    lv_err_flag := 'Y';
    RETURN SQLCODE;
   END check_error_record;

 END VAL_PROC;
```

P.S `SYS_C0012762 constraint    Check SVC_PROCESS_FLAG IN ('E', 'N', 'S')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to introduce a new value into that flag.

At the moment, the database table only allows a value of E, N or S in the column SVC_PROCESS_FLAG.

If you're trying to put a value of P in that field, you would need to replace the check constraint to also allow it as valid.

[how to modify an existing check constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077658/how-to-modify-an-existing-check-constraint)

Comment: I did a select query to find out the process flag. It seems that the SVC_PROCESS_FLAG has value 'N' but the column reflects the value 'N'. Also, where I ran the live load pl/sql block, only one row was loaded.

Comment: Thanks @Peter. I am able to resolve the issues with your timely and invaluable help. You are awesome!